# how to filter asset and meta-data property values using query builder in aem

Tags: aem, query-builder

```
type:nt:unstructured
path=/content/dam/en_us
node=jcr:content
group.1_property=Cmg_name
group.1_property.operation=exists
group.1_property.value=Web Standard
```

---

I have assets like pdf and images inside \content\dam\en-us and also i have meta data for respective assets .i want to get pdf or image by asset metadata property values .but i am notable to get exact output.I have asset c012666.png inside jcr:cotent inside metadata.now, if give property value i have to get that pdf file.so, pls can any one help???

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list the properties of a hit you have to use p.hits = full. And if you want to list all it's children you have to use the p.nodedepth = AMOUNT_OF_SUBLEVELS.

For example the query http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.hits=full&property=jcr%3atitle&property.value=Default%20Design&p.nodedepth=2

will list the properties of the the node called "Default design" and also list the children of it

Hope that this suits your needs

Here's some documentations https://hashimkhan.in/2015/12/02/query-builder/